# Specify checkout location using agent (not node)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to specify the location of the checkout using "agent" (not "node") in a Jenkinsfile?

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'my_label' }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        // Dang. my_repo has already been checked out
        dir('my_repo') {
          checkout scm
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems if you use "node" you have the ability to do this, but I can't seem to find a way to do with "agent".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set skipDefaultCheckout(), then you can checkout your SCM when you want:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'my_label' }
  options {
    skipDefaultCheckout()
  }
  stages {
    stage('Checkout') {
      steps {
        // SWEET! my_repo has not been checked out
        dir('my_repo') {
          checkout scm
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, some of the SCMs offer advanced checkout options that let you do the checkout into a different path.

Be aware, though, if you use multiple agents, you will need to manually do the checkout each time you use another agent. If MAY use the same workspace, but there is no guarantee. You should always run checkout scm, just in case it doesn't.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know you an do that!  I'm not sure what scenario warrants multiple agents, but I"ll do some research on that too. Thanks!

Comment: Say, for example, you have one specific software on one agent. Or maybe you need to run part of your build or test on Windows and part on Linux. Then you can specify different agents for each one.

Comment: So did this solve your problem? If so, I'd appreciate if you could mark this as the accepted answer.